# Binding a value to a Radiobutton and Checkbox in a ListView

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, data-binding

I have a ListView which have a column containing a radiobuttons and a column containing checkboxes. What I would like to do is bind this radiobutton to a value based on a int value on a property.

My ListView look like this:

```
   <ListView x:Name="lvSalesmen" ItemsSource="{Binding}" Margin="311,32,0,244" Grid.ColumnSpan="5">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Id" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Id}"/>
                <GridViewColumn Header="First Name" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=FirstName}"/>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Last Name" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=LastName}"/>
                <GridViewColumn Header="IsResponsible">
                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <RadioButton GroupName="IsResponsible" />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn>
                <GridViewColumn Header="IsSecondary">
                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <CheckBox />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
```

and this is where I set my DataContext in the code-behind file:

```
private void Vm_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
   lvSalesmen.DataContext = vm.Salesmen;
}
```

My ViewModel look like this:

```
    public class DistrictsListViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged {
    
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged = delegate { };
    
        private List<Salesman> _salesman;
        private ISalesmenService _salesmenService = new SalesmenService();
    
        public DistrictsListViewModel()
        {
        }
    
        public async void GetAllSalesmenWithResponsibilityByDistrictId( int id)
        {
            Salesmen = await _salesmenService.GetSalesmanReponsibilityByDistrictIdAsync(id);
        }
    
        public List<Salesman> Salesmen {
            get { return _salesman; }
            set {
                _salesman = value;
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Salesmen"));
            }
        }
```

Salesmen is a List where the Salesman object looks like this:

```
public int Id { get; set; }
public string FirstName { get; set; }
public string LastName { get; set; }
public int IsResponsible { get; set; }
public int IsSecondary { get; set; }
```

What I would like to achieve is to check the radiobutton in the row where the 'IsResponsible'-property value equals 1. Only one radiobutton can be checked at a time. This I have achieved by adding the 'GroupName'.
Furthermore, the checkbox should be checked in the 'IsSecondary'-column, if the IsSecondary-property value equals 1. Multiple checkboxes can be checked at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

You have a general type mismatch problem. `IsChecked` is generally a `bool` value but there are only `int` values available.

There are two ways to work this out:

1. You could change the type of `IsResponsible` and `IsSecondary` to `bool` in `GetSalesmanReponsibilityByDistrictIdAsync`
2. You can add another property to bind to which internally converty the value of `IsResponsible` and `IsSecondary` to `bool` in the `Get`operation

With either one of these suggestions you can then bind the given value to `IsChecked` in you *WPF* like:

```
<RadioButton IsChecked="{Binding IsResponsibleBool, Mode=OneWay}" GroupName="IsResponsible" />
<CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsResponsibleBool, Mode=OneWay}"/>
```

Possbile solution for suggestion #2:

```
public Boolean IsResponsibleBool 
{
   get => this.IsResponsbile == 1;      
}

public Boolean IsSecondaryBool 
{
   get => this.IsSecondary == 1;      
}
```